# Cocoa: How to set window title from within view controller in Swift?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I've tried to build on a Cocoa app which uses storyboard and Swift in Xcode 6. However, when I tried to alter the title of window from within `NSViewController`, the following code doesn't work.

```
self.title = "changed label"
```

When I wrote the above code in `viewDidLoad()` function, the resultant app's title still remains `window`.

Also, the following code causes an error, since View Controller doesn't have such property as `window`.

```
self.window.title = "changed label"
```

So how can I change the title of window programmatically in Cocoa app which is built on storyboard?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code:

- `viewDidLoad` is called *before* the view is added to the window
- `NSViewController` does not have a window property

To fix the first one, you could override `viewDidAppear()`. This method is called *after* the view has fully transitioned onto the screen. At that point it is already added to a window.
To get a reference to the window title, you can access a view controller's window via its view: `self.view.window.title`

Just add the following to your view controller subclass, and the window title should change:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    self.view.window?.title = "changed label"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great clarification! It's working now.

Comment: BTW, then what is the `self.title` for?

Comment: NSViewController doesn't display the title. You can use this property to store a name for this particular VC instance for later use. (E.g. to provide a name for controls that initiate a transition to this VC - A popup or a list view etc...)

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `self.view.window!.title` now?

Comment: I would use optional chaining for the window, I try to avoid ! whenever possible. `self.view.window?.title = "My Window"`.  Also, it's important to place code accessing the window in viewDidAppear (as shown above) and not in viewDidLoad, as the window will still be nil there.

Comment: If I try to `print(self.view.window?.title)` from a method I get nil, even though it gets set in `viewDidAppear()`.  How do you set/get this property outside of `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: Nevermind.  Shortly after posting the above comment I realized I was calling the method from `viewDidLoad()` and not `viewDidAppear()`, so the window was not yet attached to the view.

Comment: In MacOS 15 and using XCode 13, this doesn't work in a document-based app.  The system reverts the title to its original file name after I add a prefix to the window title, in either `viewDidAppear()` or in `makeWIndowControllers()` or after the `read()' method that analyzes the file data.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, currentDict is NSDictionary passed from previous viewController

```
var currentDict:NSDictionary?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if let myString:String = currentDict?["title"] as? String {
        self.title = myString
    }

}
```